# How to convert latex to a string that can be evaluated in JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, math, latex, mathquill

I'm using [mathquill](http://docs.mathquill.com/en/latest/Getting_Started/) that allows users to enter equations and save them. the output from mathquill is LaTex, how would one go about parsing this to an expression that can be evaluated.

```
var mathFieldSpan = document.getElementById('math-field');
var latexSpan = document.getElementById('latex');
var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2); // for backcompat
var mathField = MQ.MathField(mathFieldSpan, {
    spaceBehavesLikeTab: true, // configurable
    handlers: {
        edit: function() { // useful event handlers
            latexSpan.textContent = mathField.latex(); // simple API
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You will need some kind of mathematical parser/evaluator. There are quite a few about a search for "evaluate latex" gives a good number of hits. 

Latex is a bit tricky as its very wide-ranging and designed for display rather than its semantical structure. So you can get expressions like "\underbrace{ a+b+\cdots+z }_{26}". Hence you will need to restrict the allowable input somewhat. Remove the fancy stuff and limited subset becomes fairly easy to parse.

Comment: One method might be you use mathjax to convert the latex to the mathml 
 xml format. Once its in mathml it might be easier to use a standard xml parser.